# Can SVN Save Folder Icon

Tags: windows, svn, icons, windows-shell

Is it possible for SVN to save the specific folder's icon so when I check out a directory on another computer, the folder icons stay the same? I'm referring to the folder icon itself, instead of the icon overlay.

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VOQV.png)

[What I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79kUv.png)

Comment: I'm not a windows user, so I can't tell you about icons specifically.  But in general, SVN can save anything that can be represented as a file or directory in your svn tree.  Your icon definitions may be in a hidden directory; in that case, `svn add` that hidden directory.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Stewart's answer above, I figured out a work-around on Windows.

1. add each folder's desktop.ini file to SVN
2. create a folder with all the icons that gets downloaded along with the directory
3. update each folders desktop.ini file to be a relative location, and point to the icon directory you just made
4. set all folders to read only mode using a batch command [for /d /r %%i in (*) do @attrib +r "%%i"]